# destructure array of objects containing quoted, non-valid identifiers

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of objects:

```js
let object = [
  {
    id: '01',
    name: 'Subject',
    'Data.type': 'maths',
  },
  {
    id: '02',
    name: 'Subject',
    'Data.type': 'science',
  },
  {
    id: '04',
    name: 'language',
    'Data.type': 'node',
  },
  {
    id: '05',
    name: 'language',
    'Data.type': 'node',
  }
  /*...*/
];

object.map((value) => {
  console.log(value["Data.type"]);
})
```

I have tried to destructure them in a map function like the following:

```
const data = [];
object.map((value) => {
  const { name, type } = value;
  if (!data.some((obj) => obj.name === name && obj["Data.type"] === ["Data.type"])) {
    
    data.push({ name, type });
    console.log(name, type); 
// rest of the coding part
  }
});
```

I want to distinguish repeated data inside the map function and remove duplicates based off data type.

Comment: The structure doesn't match the code. I don't see a `type` key for example. What result are you trying to get here? Never use `map` for a side effect like this; just `return` the data and assign the newly-allocated array that `map` gives you to a variable: `const data = foo.map(e => return the new value)`, not `const data = []; foo.map(e => data.push(the new value))`.

Comment: yes that's what i'm asking what should i write to get type in place of `const { name type} = value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can destructure by mentioning the property and variable with following syntax `["Data.type"]:type`, then value for property `Data.type` will be placed in `type` variable

```
object.map(({id,name,["Data.type"]:type}) => type)
```

Comment: os i have to write like this ?? `const { name, ["Data.type"]:type } = value;`

Comment: Exactly, yes mate

Comment: and this will remain same or need some changes ?? `if (!data.some((obj) => obj.name === name && obj["Data.type"] === ["Data.type"])) {
    
    data.push({ name, type });`

Comment: change this part `&& obj["Data.type"] === type`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use [_.uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#uniqBy) method by [lodash](https://lodash.com) in order to remove all the duplicated objects by specify the duplication criteria with relative ease... like so:

```
  let array = [
    {
     id: '01',
     name: 'Subject',
     'Data.type': 'maths',
  },
  {
    id: '02',
    name: 'Subject',
    'Data.type': 'science',
  },
  {
    id: '04',
    name: 'language',
    'Data.type': 'node',
  },
  {
    id: '05',
    name: 'language',
    'Data.type': 'node',
  }
  /*...*/
];

const newArray = _.uniqBy(array, 'Data.type')
```